# Spring @Validated - with a super set of values

Tags: java, spring, spring-validator

I have a user input mapping class which has got a Boolean object:

```
...
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Approval Status")
    @NotNull(message = "{workspace.isApproved.notNull}")
    private Boolean isApproved;
...
```

from the front end if user sends `123` as value of the `isApproved` it translates that as `true`, what I want to do it restrict the values to `0` and `1` i.e. there should a validation error if any other value is sent from the front end.

Comment: I would be interested to understand why this is happening, @Toseef, can you please execute the same scenario with value `120`, `121`, `122` and `124`, I am thinking in network byte order and the size of datatype `Boolean`

Comment: Yes @Vishrant any numeric value ends up in true and empty and 0 end up in false

Comment: what about negative value?

Comment: I tried -123 ended up in true

Comment: so my hypothesis is all non-zero values are treated as true. anyways my below answer would have helped?

Comment: I will try that tomorrow morning and get back to mark it as right answer if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a range of ints you want to specify, try looking at the `@Min` and `@Max` annotations. If it's only these two values, you could also simply have a RegEx.

Ex:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "(0|1)")
private String testField;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Java Bean Validation`. Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) you can use following field (or method or class) level annotations:

- ```
  @Max(1)
  @Min(0)
  private Boolean isApproved;
  ```
- ```
  @Pattern(regexp="(0|1)")
  private Boolean isApproved;
  ```

These constraints are available under package: `javax.validation.constraints`